# How to ssh into another machine immediately after logging into a machine

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

Problem: The location I'm working from cannot ssh into the master node for my application, say **10.30.30.1** which is hosted by another country. To solve this, I have a jump box which I can ssh from my location say **10.50.50.1**

And after logging into the jump box, I again run the command **ssh 10.30.30.1**

Is there any way to save me a step of first logging into the jump box and then ssh into master node, because that's the only thing I use the jump box for.

Can I configure the jump box to directly run that ssh command the moment I log in?
Are there any commands which allow me to login directly to master via the jump box in a single command or putty / MOBA XTerm configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you first execute `ssh server1`, then on `server1`, you execute `ssh server2`. The thing you want is when you execute `ssh server1` on your local computer, you can automatically login to `server2`.

The way to do this is add a script that runs automatically when you login to `server1`. You can do this by just adding the code `ssh server2` into your `~/.bashrc` file (if you are using Ubuntu. Or in other OS, the file name is similar to `~/.bashxxx`).

But after doing so, you still need to type password for `server2` every time you login into `server1`. If you don't want to type `server2`'s password by hand, you can use a password-free ssh connection from `server1` to `server2`. See [this page](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) to find out how.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, Thanks

Comment: hey, not i didn't have sudo rights on the machine and i could not install netcat on it, thus wasn't able to try it out. This answer worked for me, so i picked it up.

Answer (score 3):

Put the following lines into your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host target-host 
    ProxyJump jump-host
```

This assumes both the server and the client running `OpenSSH >= 7.3`. For older versions you can use `ProxyCommand` and `netcat` instead of `ProxyJump`. `netcat` must be installed on the jump host:

```
Host target-host
    ProxyCommand ssh jump-host netcat -w 120 %h %p
```